# How to extract only the last two lines of text from a string?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

`A1`:

```
88'



21



Corinthians
SE Palmeiras
```

`A2`:

```
90'
+1


03

Club Sporting Canamy
Reboceros de La Piedad
```

Current formula in `B1`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(A1:A),char(10))),,2),"offset 1")))
```

My expected result is to collect the last two lines of text that are the two names, leaving the first name in one Column and the second name in another Column, like this:

```
COLUMN B                   COLUMN C

Corinthians                SE Palmeiras
Club Sporting Canamy       Reboceros de La Piedad
```

The problem is that depending on the number of lines that have text in each of the cells, the result for headers and the removal of the `QUERY` *offset* ends up being different, what formula can I use to always **collect the last two lines** of text in the string?

Comment: Hi mate @Sergey , I added and got the ```=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(A1:A),"(.*\n.*)$"),CHAR(10)))``` formula, it worked but unfortunately I couldn't understand how it worked to reach this result, could you explain to me if there are any usage limitations please?

Comment: this formula simply selects the last two rows from cells A:A. Your problem is different.

Comment: @Sergey But it worked perfectly for what I needed, the result was exactly what I expected, so I asked if there could be any limitations.

Comment: this formula seems to do what is needed `=ARRAYFORMULA((if(A1:A<>"",split(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"(.*\n.*)$"),char(10)),)))`

Comment: Correct @Sergey , instead of adding the IF I put an IFERROR to make the formula a little smaller, but that's exactly it. If you want to create the answer, I am available to mark it as a solution!

Comment: the split and regex functions have no limitations in this case, because they work in an array formula and process each cell in the A:A range row by row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the formula [REGEXEXTRACT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) to perform this task. The regular expression `"(.*\n.*)$"` allows you to select a line of any characters `.*` + a line break `\n` + another line of any characters `.*` from the end `$`.

As a result, we have a cell with two lines inside. Split it into two columns with [SPLIT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625) formula.

Now we wrap everything in an array formula with a check for empty rows. If original row is empty, we skip it

`=ARRAYFORMULA((if(A1:A<>"",split(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"(.*\n.*)$"),char(10)),)))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

`=split(substitute(mid(substitute(A1,char(10),char(9670),(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))+1*COUNTA(A1) -2)),(search(char(9670),substitute(A1,char(10),char(9670),(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))+1*COUNTA(A1) -2)))+1),(len(A1)-search(char(9670),substitute(A1,char(10),char(9670),(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))+1*COUNTA(A1)-2))))),char(10),","),",")`

**Logic**

- Count the number of line feeds in a given cell
  `LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))+1*COUNTA(A1)`
- Substitute a unique character in place of the 2nd last line feed
  `substitute(A1,char(10),char(9670),<line feed count>-2)`
- Get the position of the unique character
  `search(char(9670),<substituted text>)`
- Get the length of the original cell
  `len(A1)`
- Extract the text between the unique character and the end of the string
  `mid()`
- Substitute a comma for the remaining line feed
  `substitute(<the text>,char(10),",")`
- Split the result by comma
  `split(<the result>,",")`

Comment: Hello friend @Tedinoz , when trying to use in Array as I mentioned in the question, ended up returning in error, but I believe I can adjust. But I'm leaning to mark Sergey's answer as the solution because it got much smaller and by testing it searches for the last two values. Anyway I gave an upvote on your answer for thanks for the help! But if by chance he (Sergey) doesn't come up with the answer, I'll give you the solution.

Comment: The answer by @Sergey is by far more efficient and elegant than this.